# Silverlight Excel Automation Factory API Documentation

Tags: silverlight, excel, comautomationfactory

Silverlight Excel Automation Factory API Documentation
Hi Im using Excel Automation Factory to export data from silverlight to excel. Problem is I can't find documentation on using excel this way. All I could find where some small tutorial from which i could extract some data 
like :

```
dynamic excel;
excel = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
excel.Visible = true;
dynamic workbook = excel.workbooks;
workbook.Add();
```

but thas all!
Where Can I find Some Excel Automation Factory Documentation?

Answer (score 1):

refer MSDN:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

although there isn't much documentation on same.